# Can someone explain what the broadcast assignment is in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am brand new to Python and I have an assignment to use broadcast assignment.  I have read about it in numpy docs but I still do not really understand what it does in relation to what I have to do.

'''
Now we are going to set every entry in the ESTGEST column of births to np.nan using broadcast assignment.
'''
Could someone help understand what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html?

Comment: Broadcasting can be tricky to understand when dealing with arrays of different dimensions.  But in your case it looks like one argument is a scalar.  That's an easy case - to do and to understand.  `x[:] = np.nan` just assigns that value to all elements of `x`.  Under the covers `numpy` is using its broadcasting rules, but this case is so simple that we don't normally think about it that way.